# Why selenium webdriver for IE not able to click an element in iframe with specific CSS?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer

I'm trying to automate a click in iframe. I've removed all the un-necessary code piece and sharing the minimal code which causes the issue. Here is the extracted code,

**a.html** -> points to b.html in iframe

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<IFRAME width="100%" height="100%" id="iframe" src="b.html" style="HEIGHT: 100% !important; WIDTH: 100% !important">

</IFRAME>
</body>
</html>
```

**b.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
DIV {
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#left_container_menu {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    left: 9px;
    width: 190px;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: -3px;
}
BODY {
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
}
BODY {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
BODY {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
HTML {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.menu_content_in {
    border-left: solid #D1D1D1 1px;
    border-right: solid #D1D1D1 1px;
    border-bottom: solid #D1D1D1 1px;
    padding: 2px 0px 4px 2px;
}
A {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 3px;
}
</style>
</head>

<BODY>
<DIV id=left_container_menu>

<DIV id=ctl00_Menu_ctl02_Submenu_header_CollapsablePanelUpdatePanel>
<DIV class=menu_content_in>

<A tabIndex=-1 href="e.html">test1</A><BR>
<A tabIndex=-1 href="d.html">test2</A><BR>
<A tabIndex=-1 href="c.html">test3</A><BR></DIV></DIV>

</DIV>


</BODY>
</html>
```

Now, when I try to click the element using following c# code via selenium web driver, the `test3` link is not clicked. It doesn't give me any error/warning. It silently goes through the click method. Code is as follows,

```
d.SwitchTo().Frame("iframe");

IWebElement e = d.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_Menu_ctl02_Submenu_header_CollapsablePanelUpdatePanel']/div/a[3]"));
e.Click();

d.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Why is the link `test3` not clicked?

The interesting fact is when, I remove following CSS code, I'm able to automate the click.

```
#left_container_menu {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    left: 9px;
    width: 190px;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: -3px;
}
```

What is so special about this CSS? I want to make the element clickable. How do I do that?

**Note**: I can't change the html source code, due to legacy reasons. But I change anything via c# to make the click happen. Any pointers is greatly appreciated.

My package list,

[image: packages]

I can't automate the click on Chrome/Firefox, as the website works only on IE. I'm attaching my IE version as well.

[image: My IE version]

Comment: I tried to test your code on my side and it is working on my side. It is clicking the Test 3 link. It is also working with the left_container_menu CSS class. I suggest trying to put an alert message on the Test3 link to test it again. Let us know about your test results.

Comment: Interesting, I tried following `<A tabIndex=-1 onclick="alert('hi')" href="c.html">test3</A>` and I don't see the alert box. Can it be due to different webdriver versions? I'm updating the question and attaching the packages list.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT is it possible to share the working visual code zip file with me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I am using on my side. I have just added your code to my test code.

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

namespace selenium_IE_automation
{
    class Program
    {     
        private const string IE_DRIVER_PATH = @"D:\D drive backup\selenium web drivers\";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost/a.html";
            var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);    
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            try
            { 
                driver.SwitchTo().Frame("iframe");
                IWebElement leverancierlinkElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_Menu_ctl02_Submenu_header_CollapsablePanelUpdatePanel']/div/a[3]"));
                leverancierlinkElement.Click();
                driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit:**

**IE driver server version:**

[image]

**Selenium web driver version:**

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the drivers screenshots with version numbers?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I have added the version screenshots.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it on actual project and get back to you.

Comment: Let us know if it works for you or not. It can be possible that the issue caused by any other reason or the code.